# How to represent a property name as datetime in mongoengine class model

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

[image]

How to represent a class with following data. Here i have seen fields, **bp_data** has nested objects, the objects are not in constant name, it represents each object with internet current datetime.

And also that **bp_data** objects are not array, its a document,
[image]

Any help to represent above fig data in a mongoengine collection class.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores data in [BSON](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html), which only permits string for field name.

In order to use a date for the field name, you would have to convert it to string when storing in the database.

Comment: HI @joe, can i know, how to represent that in mongoengine collection class

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `EmbeddedDocumentField()` for bp_data to act as a separate document but is embedded to the object with the patient_id field.

For example:

```
class Bp_data(EmbeddedDocument):
   a_string_field = StringField()
   internet_dates = ListField(DateTimeField())

class ParentObject(Document):
   patient_id = StringField()
   bp_data = EmbeddedDocumentField(Bp_data)
```

Considering that you have many instances of bp_data, you should also consider `EmbeddedDocumentListField()` which essentially a list of `EmbeddedDocuments`.

[1] https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument

[2] http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=datetimefield#mongoengine.fields.DateTimeField

Comment: Bp_data objects are list of various objects, those objects represents various internet datetime documents. Can you show me, how to create that in mongoengine class.

Comment: I edited my initial answer. This will work for your case. Please take a look at the two references to understand how to handle these fields.